# Strange behaviour with powershell generic list

Tags: .net, powershell

So,?I’m doing some filtering on a generic list and I found by chance with the logging that it’s doing a bizarre thing when I use the where method. The 2 separate strings become one, separated by a space but still return the list object has anyone encountered this? I have some example below

```
[List[object]$calcUsers = @()

[List[string]]$userDNs = @(“CN=some,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS”, “CN=another,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS”)
$userDNs 
<# output
CN=some,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS 
CN=another,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS
#>
$userDNs = $userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_})

$userDNs
<# output
CN=some,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS CN=another,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS
#>
```

Comment: Is ```$calUsers``` in your ```Where``` a typo vs your ```$calcUsers``` variable?

Comment: `$userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_})` produces a different object type than `[list[string]]`. So when the result is cast to `[list[string]]`, which is what happens when you try assign the output to `$userDNs`, you get the result you see.

Comment: MCLAYTON yes that’s a typo my bad.

Comment: One workaround for your situation is to unroll your new collection and convert each item to a string --> `$userDNs = $userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_}).foreach([string])`.

Comment: Or use a new variable and be a little more dynamic :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object `$userDNs` is created as a list of strings.

```
[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$userDNs = @(“CN=some,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS”, “CN=another,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS”)
$userDNs.GetType().FullName
```

**Output:**

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

The `where()` method outputs an object of type `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]`. Notice how each item is a wrapped `[psobject]` type.

```
$userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_}).GetType().FullName
```

**Output:**

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]
```

The `where()` method is not unrolling the collection and outputting single objects of type `[string]`. So when the entire collection object is assigned to `$userDNs`, the object is converted to a `[string]` because that's what `$userDNs` contains. You can see the same result by executing `[string]$userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_})`. In this case, you need to either unroll collection before assigning it back or convert each item in the collection back into a `[string]`.

**Option 1: Unrolling with Where-Object**

```
$userDNs = $userDNs | Where {$calUsers -notContains $_}
```

**Option 2: Converting each item to String through casting.
Note that this changes the collection object type to System.Array before being converted into a list.**

```
$userDNs = [string[]]$userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_})
```

**Option 3: Enumerate the collection and convert each item to string**

```
$userDNs = $userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_}).foreach([string])
```

**Option 4: Unrolling with Foreach-Object**

```
$userDNs = $userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_}) | Foreach-Object { $_ }
```

**Option 5: Use a new variable and let PowerShell unroll the items later**

```
$userDNList = $userDNs.Where({$calUsers -notContains $_})
$userDNList # unrolled
```

Comment: **Option 6**: avoid _strongly typed variables_. Use `$userDNs = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]@(“CN=some,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS”, “CN=another,OU=User,DC=my,DC=Ad,DC=SYS”)`

Comment: I Marked your answer as the correct one adminofthings indeed I knew I could assign it to a new variable and it was correct I was more looking at the reasons it was doing it… very informative. Thank you!